# how to add icon in tab host instead of text

Tags: java, android

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewpagerAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewpagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"Home");
        viewpagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopFreeFragment(),"TopFree");
        viewpagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopPaidFragment(),"TopPaid");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewpagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        Home.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconimage1_design));
        TopFree.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconimage2_design));
        TopPaid.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconimage3_design));
    }
}
```

In last 3 statement Home,TopFree,TopPaid,shom in red marks what text should i provide instead of these three name.
any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a `Tab` object and call `setIcon`.

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.iconimage1_design);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.iconimage2_design);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.iconimage3_design);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to replace the text indicator with your custom indicator :

```
int numTabs = 3;
int resIds = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3};

for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
    RelativeLayout tab = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_sliding_tab_indicator_layout, null);
    ((ImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon)).setImageResource(resIds[i]);
    //...
    //set other values (text, image source etc.)
    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tab);
}
```

or if you just have to use an icon then use @Juan's code, or a modified version :

```
int numTabs = 3;
int resIds = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3};

for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(resIds[i]);
}
```